# What advantages are there of using "declare -a" to declare arrays in bash?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, shell

What advantage is there to declaring an array using `declare -a`?

eg; does using `declare -a foo=(a b c)` provide any benefits over using `foo=(a b c)`?

Comment: This might help others who come along this way: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-declare-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `declare` a variable in bash, it becomes locally scoped. This is the same as using the `local` builtin. Outside of scoping, no benefit is gained. The only variable that must be declared in bash is an associative array with `-A`.